# Using multiprocessing with Pandas to read, modify and write thousands csv files

Tags: python, pandas, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

So I have about 5000 csv files under one directory, which contains stocks' minutes data. Each file is named by their symbol. like stock AAPL is named as AAPL.csv.

I try to do some clean up and editing on each of them. In this case, I try to convert one column which contains unix epoch datatime into readable date and time. I also want to change a label of one column.

I try to use multiprocessing to speed up the process. But first try just kill my Macbook.

I run it inside VScode's jupyter notebook. If that matters.

I wonder what did I do wrong and how to improve. And how to handle similar tasks in python and pandas.

Thank you!

Here is my code.

```
# Define operations will be used in multiprocessing handling
def clean_up(file,fail_list):
    print('Working on {}'.format(file))
    stock = pd.read_csv('./Data/minutes_data/' + file)

    try:
        #Convert datetime columns into readable date and time column
        stock['Date'] = stock.apply(lambda row: epoch_converter.get_date_from_mill_epoch(row['datetime']), axis=1)
        stock['Time'] = stock.apply(lambda row: epoch_converter.get_time_from_mill_epoch(row['datetime']), axis=1)

        #Rename 'Unnamed: 0' column into 'Minute'
        stock.rename(columns={'Unnamed: 0':'Minute'}, inplace=True)

        #Write it back to new file
        stock.to_csv('./Data/working_data/' + file)
    except:
        print('{} not successful'.format(file))
        fail_list = fail_list.append(file)
        fail_list.to_csv('./failed_list.csv')



#Get file list to working on.
file_list = os.listdir('./Data/minutes_data/')

#prepare failed_list
fail_list = pd.DataFrame([])
#Loop through each file
processes = []
for file in file_list:
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=clean_up, args=(file,fail_list,))
    processes.append(p)
    p.start()

for process in processes:
    process.join()
```

### Update: CSV_FILE_SAMPLE

,open,high,low,close,volume,datetime
0,21.9,21.9,21.9,21.9,200,1596722940000
0,20.0,20.0,19.9937,19.9937,200,1595266500000
1,20.0,20.0,19.9937,19.9937,500,1595266800000
2,20.0,20.0,19.9937,19.9937,1094,1595267040000
3,20.0,20.0,20.0,20.0,200,1595268240000

## Final Update:

Combine answers from @furas and @jsmart, the script managed to reduce processing time of 5000 csv from hours to under 1 minutes (Under 6 core i9 on Macbook pro). I'm happy. You guys are awesome. Thanks!

The final scripts is here:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import multiprocessing
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename='./log.log',level=logging.DEBUG)

file_list = os.listdir('./Data/minutes_data/')

def cleanup(file):
    print('Working on ' + file)
    stock = pd.read_csv('./Data/minutes_data/' + file)
    
    try:
        #Convert datetime columns into readable date and time column
        stock['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(stock['datetime'],unit='ms',utc=True).dt.tz_convert('America/New_York').dt.date
        stock['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(stock['datetime'],unit='ms',utc=True).dt.tz_convert('America/New_York').dt.time

        #Rename 'Unnamed: 0' column into 'Minute'
        stock.rename(columns={'Unnamed: 0':'Minute'}, inplace=True)

        #Write it back to new file
        stock.to_csv('./Data/working_data/' + file)
    except:
        print(file + ' Not successful')
        logging.warning(file + ' Not complete.')



pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
pool.map(cleanup, file_list)
```

Comment: did you get an error message? what was it?

Comment: and can you provide an example csv file

Comment: using `multiprocessing.Process` you creates `5000` processes at the same time. Better use ie. `multiprocessing.Pool(10)` to run only `10` processes at the same time. And when some process ends work then it uses it with next file on list.

Comment: @anon01 Unfortunate I didn't able to get error code, my mac just freezing and I had to do a hard restart. I have update a simple csv file which countians less data but the format is same.

Comment: It's super helpful to profile first - that will let you know where the slowdown is.  If it's just waiting for file IO, a thread pool might be a better option.

Comment: documentation for [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) even show `Pool` in first example.

Comment: with `Pool` you can also use `return` to send failed file to main process and then it can save it. Saving in the same file `failed_list.csv` in different processes may gives wrong results. Besides processes don't share variables and every process will have own copy of empty `failed_file` and it will save only one value and remove previous value in file `'./failed_list.csv'`.

Comment: It’s possibly already taken longer messing up with Multiprocessing than it would if you’d simply left the non-multiprocessing version running. -can you simply leave it running overnight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Process` in loop you create 5000 process at the same time

You could use `Pool` to control how many processes works at the same time - and it will automatically free process with next file.

It also can use `return` to send name of failed file to main process and it can save file once. Using the same file in many processes can makes wrong data in this file. Besides processes don't share variables and every process will have own empty DataFrame and later will save only own failed file - so it will remove previous content.

```
def clean_up(file):
    # ... code ...
    
        return None  # if OK
    except:
        return file  # if failed
    
    
# --- main ---

# get file list to working on.
file_list = sorted(os.listdir('./Data/minutes_data/'))

with multiprocessing.Pool(10) as p:
    failed_files = p.map(clean_up, file_list)

# remove None from names
failed_files = filter(None, failed_files)

# save all
df = pd.DataFrame(failed_files)
df.to_csv('./failed_list.csv')
```

---

There is also `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool` which uses `threads` instead of `processes`.

Module [concurrent.futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) has also `ThreadPoolExecutor` and `ProcessPoolExecutor`

You can also try to do it with external modules - but I don't remeber which can be useful.

Comment: Thank you @furas! I think I didn’t understand how multiprocessing works at first place. Your answer  is very helpful!

Comment: I was thinking also about external modules like `ray`, `dask`, `joblib` but I don't have experience - see also [6 Python libraries for parallel processing](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3542595/6-python-libraries-for-parallel-processing.html). On Linux I can also use program [GNU parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) and script which works siple file and do `ls | parallel -n 10 python clean_up.py`

Answer (score 1):

The original post asked "...how to handle similar tasks in python and pandas."

- Replacing `.apply(..., axis=1)` can increase throughput by 100x or better.
- Here is an example with 10_000 rows of data:

```
%%timeit
df['date'] = df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x['timestamp'], unit='ms'), axis=1)
792 ms ± 26.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Re-write as:

```
%%timeit
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], unit='ms')
4.88 ms ± 38.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Sample data:

```
print(df['timestamp'].head())
0    1586863008214
1    1286654914895
2    1436424291218
3    1423512988135
4    1413205308057
Name: timestamp, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Sorry but I’m not fully understand your solution. Do you mean Pandas has built in functions to convert epoch milliseconds format into readable date and time format?

Comment: Yes.  The argument `unit='ms'` indicates that the original values are in milliseconds since the epoch.  And you can use `.dt.date` or `.dt.time` to pull out just date, or just time.  Docs are here [to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)

Comment: You made my day. Thanks!